# I am trying to install Turck MMCache but some files are not found as instruction

Tags: php, security, obfuscation

i want to protect my php source code, i tried Zend Guard, Ioncube, source guardian but those are all too costly. Then i try to install Turck MMCache but some files are not found as instruction which are marked as bold. i attached my zip file. please help

See Full instruction at: http://turck-mmcache.sourceforge.net/index_old.html#win

Zip Source File: https://sourceforge.net/projects/turck-mmcache/files/latest/download?source=files

Windows Installation Notes
To build Turck MMCache on Windows platform you will need MS Visual Studio C++ 6.0.

Step 1. Compiling Turck MMCache

- Unpack php sources.
- Put mmcache sources under "ext/mmcache".
- Put **"php4ts.lib"** into "ext/mmcache".
- Copy **"main/config.w32.h.in"** into "main/config.w32.h".
- Open project file **"ext/mmcache/mmcache.dsp"**.
- Select release configuration and build "mmcache.dll".

Comment: > "i want to protect my php source code" [Good luck with that](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/753).

Comment: That project was abandoned many years ago. If became eaccelerator, which is also dead. You may be able to use xcache. If you have $5 to spare and not too much code, you could use the ionCube online Encoder. If you're not trying to make money from your code, why not release as opensource. Will be good practice for you ahead of perhaps a bigger commercial project in the future. If you do want to make money from your code, don't waste time trying to cut corners, save up and invest in a professional tool when close to release. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.